# Create a new List from existing one and group objects

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I have a List<> with User objects (username(string) and grade(string))

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();
```

The List gets populated with values from DB(or Text File) and I have a List with 5 objects:

```
user1 A
user1 B
user2 A
user2 G
user3 D
```

I want to modify the List(or create a new List) so the result should be a new List with htis values:

```
user1 A,B
user2 A,G
user3 D
```

I tried GroupBy :

```
var result = jquery.GroupBy(u => u.username).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()).Select(g => g.Key);
```

But I want to have the result in a new List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
var query = users.GroupBy(x => x.UserName).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
                                        .Select(x => new { UserName = x.Key, Grades = String.Join(",", x.Select(z => z.Grade)) });
```

Working [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h7Twg5).

Comment: It works very well. So if I extend my User Object with another element lets say firstname, secondname this could work without greater changes?

Comment: @user576914 - Yup, that depends on how you wanna group & what output you are expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var result = users
            .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
            .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Grades = string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.Grade) });
```

Here is [code sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dIIrHk)

Answer (score 1):

You could built a new type, that will hold the information you want, like

```
public class UserGrade
{
    // the user's name.
    public string UserName { get; set;}

    // a comma separated list of the grades achieved by the user.
    public string Grades { get; set; }
}
```

Then we groub by our results by the username and we select for each group a bew `UserGrade` object. Last we call `ToList`, in order we get our result as a list:

```
var result = jquery.GroupBy(u => u.username)
                   .Select(x=> new UserGrade{
                       UserName = x.Key,
                       Grades = String.Join(",",x.Select(y=>y.Grade)
                 }).ToList();
```

**Note**
You could avoid the definition of the new type. In this case your list, will hold a sequence of obejcts of an anonymous type.